# custom font in react native

Tags: ios, react-native, fonts

I try using custom font in react native app ,
create assets/fonts/ folder in root of project and put fonts in there.
create `react-native.config.js` and write ,

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
  assets: ['./assets/fonts/'],
};
```

and try `react-native link`
it is working in android but not working in ios

```
react-native: 0.60.5
npm: 6.11.0
node: 10.16.0
```

Comment: What exactly are you exporting inside project? Have you tried rebuilding the project?

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17641

Answer (score 0):

**Android will use the font name but in IOS it will use the “PostScript name(Please check may be this is the issue)”.**

Suppose you have a font "SFUIDisplayBold.otf" . You have link the font . It will work in Android but not in IOS . Because PostScript name of font is“SFUIDisplay-Bold.otf” so for IOS you have to use "SFUIDisplay-Bold.otf" despite the fact that we have added font with name  "SFUIDisplayBold.otf". ([See Details)](https://medium.com/@mehran.khan/ultimate-guide-to-use-custom-fonts-in-react-native-77fcdf859cf4)

You can see the PostScript name of fonts in font book

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Custom fonts are not bundled automatically for IOS. You need to link them for IOS manually.

A detailed instruction can be found at [Custom Fonts in React Native for iOS & Android Builds](https://medium.com/@kswanie21/custom-fonts-in-react-native-tutorial-for-ios-android-76ceeaa0eb78)

The last step was the key for me to make this work. Make sure you use the PostScript name of the font when adding `fontFamily` to your style.